Is the embedding $X_T := \mathbf{H}(\text{curl}) \cap \mathbf{H}_0(\text{div}^0) \rightarrow \mathbf{H}_0(\text{div}^0) $ compact?
I am currently studying embeddings in Sobolev spaces related to computational electromagnetics, and I came across a problem that I'm not entirely sure about.
Specifically, I am interested in the compactness of the embedding:
$$
X_T := \mathbf{H}(\text{curl}) \cap \mathbf{H}_0(\text{div}^0) \rightarrow \mathbf{H}_0(\text{div}^0).
$$
I know that the embedding
$$
X_T := \mathbf{H}(\text{curl}) \cap \mathbf{H}_0(\text{div}^0) \rightarrow \mathbf{H}(\text{div})
$$
is compact, but I'm uncertain about how the boundary condition $ \mathbf{H}_0(\text{div}^0) $ (i.e., normal-component-free boundary condition and divergence free) affects the compactness of the embedding.
Any insights or references that could help clarify this would be greatly appreciated!

The boundary conditions appear naturally when we calculate the domain of co-derivatives of differential operators with pivot space being $L_2$. For example
the adjoint of $\mathrm{grad}$ and $\mathrm{curl}$ are $\mathrm{div}_0 $ and $\mathrm{curl}_0$ respectively.
I don't know all the details, but I know
a general reference that contains the proof and could help.
An Elementary Proof for a Compact Embedding
Result in Generalized Electromagnetic Theory

Thank you for your insightful response.  Since it delves into these concepts using the language of differential forms, it could be hard for me to understand the details.
